# Listening to batch queries with PreparedStatement in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-processing

Let's say we have this snippet:

```
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);//commit trasaction manually

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
            + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?,?)";              
PreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

for(int i=0;i<5000;i++){
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "im_a_new_user");
    preparedStatement.setString(3, "admin");
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, "00:00:00.000");
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
}

preparedStatement.executeBatch();

dbConnection.commit();
```

It basically adds 5000 batch inserts to the `PreparedStatement` and executes them.

Now, i have a GUI with a `JProgressBar`, and I would like to listen to the `PreparedStatement` after the `executeBatch()` call, in order to know how many queries have been executed and update the progress bar. I already have the code to update the progressbar but i don't know how to listen to `PreparedStatement`, is it possible to do that?

Comment: may be you take one global counter in for loop and increment it every time query executes

Comment: @shreyanshjogi as you can see, i'm calling the `executeBatch` method **only one time**, i'm only adding batches 5000 times but all queries are executed when the `executeBatch` method is called, so i can't use a global counter.

Comment: instead of executing 5000 at once, you can define a bulk size and update progress bar after each bulk is executed.

Comment: @ogzd How can i do that? Post an answer please :)

Answer (score 3):

You can divide whole data into bulks and treat each of them individually and update the progress bar afterwards.

```
private int BULKSIZE = 100; // define your own bulk size

for(int j = 0; j < 5000; j += BULKSIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < BULKSIZE; ++i) 
    {
         preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
         preparedStatement.setString(2, "im_a_new_user");
         preparedStatement.setString(3, "admin");
         preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, "00:00:00.000");
         preparedStatement.addBatch();
    }
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

Comment: Well, the reason i want to listen to the `PreparedStatement` is that i'd like to update the progress bar everytime a query is executed using a batch instead of using a for loop with query execution on each loop. I'd like to add all queries to the batch and listen to it instead of executing queries in the for loop

Comment: @BackSlash There is no such functionality in `PreparedStatement` or JDBC in general, so this solution is the closest you can get